# can't change all font names

Tags: jquery, font-face

The font names are like `Lobster1.4` , `1KreemDNA` , `0LumaxBigCapsDNA` etc.

```
$('.fmsg_class').css("font-family",font);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The fonts you've listed are not system fonts and as such will not work on a website unless they have been specifically installed by the user on their machine.

There are methods you can use to negate the installation of fonts, such as Cufon or Google Web Fonts.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. 
I installed those fonts to the server and passed the font family
like 
$('.fmsg_class').css("font-family","font");
and now its working properly.